# How to set a delay in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making a **Simon** game, while doing it, I created an method that called "Computer" that is activated when the game is starting and after that, every time after the player successes to repeat the sequence.

Here is the code:

```
    private void Computer(){
    rounds.setText("Round " + index);
    new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            ResetArray(Player);
            //Pushing buttons
            Red.setClickable(false);
            Blue.setClickable(false);
            Green.setClickable(false);
            Yellow.setClickable(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final int temp=Game[i];
                        if (temp == 0)
                        {
                            Red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red1);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    StartSound(red);
                                    Red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                                }
                            }, 100);
                        }
                        if (temp == 1)
                        {
                            Green.setImageResource(R.drawable.green1);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    StartSound(green);
                                    Green.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                                }
                            }, 100);
                        }
                        if (temp == 2)
                        {
                            Blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue1);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    StartSound(blue);
                                    Blue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                                }
                            }, 100);
                        }

                        if (temp == 3)
                        {
                            Yellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow1);
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    StartSound(yellow);
                                    Yellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                                }
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }


                Red.setClickable(true);
                Blue.setClickable(true);
                Green.setClickable(true);
                Yellow.setClickable(true);

            }
    }.start();
    }
```

So basically, what iv'e done here is a short delay, of 500 milliseconds, and then it is starting with the self "pushing". This is for create some space between the beginning of the game/starting a new round.

Index- round number.

Game- an array that iv'e created, where there is 50 random numbers which presents the sequence, every round i'm adding one for the index.

Red, Green, Blue, Yellow - References for ImageButtons.

The handler delay is to give some time between the button pressing (which presented by switching the image resource to a same color but brighter, that gives the effect of pressing a button) and un-press it, without it, the changing will be so fast so the player will not be able to see any graphical change.

Basically I need a way to stop the program for a while between each pushing. I need a delayer that will delay the loop every time at it's beginning. The countdowntimer and the Handler are not suitable because the program keeps "running" after the declaring and setting those, the only effect is that the buttons are pushed together but in a delay, which is not what I need.

The result now is that the buttons are seems pushed **together** and I need to separate their pushing in some way.
Iv'e tried everything, and I could not find nothing.

Thanks,
Ziv.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Handler` and `postDelayed(...)` *IS* exactly what you need but you're a approaching it wrong.

Basically what you are doing is running through your `for` loop almost instantly and at each loop you're calling `postDelayed(...)` with a delay of 100ms.

I'll explain further - suppose `index` is 4 and it only takes 1ms to go through each run of the `for` loop. When the 4 runs of the loop are complete you'll have 4 `postDelayed` events with times of 100ms, 99ms, 98ms & 96ms - - to all intents and purposes, when they trigger they all appear to trigger at once.

One easy way around this with your code is to increase each delay based on the loop count...

```
int delayTime;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    delaytime = (i + 1) * 100;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int temp=Game[i];
    if (temp == 0)
    {
        Red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red1);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                StartSound(red);
                Red.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            }
        }, delayTime); // NOTE USING delayTime AS THE DELAY
    }
    //
    // REPEAT THE ABOVE CODE FOR BLUE, GREEN & YELLOW HANDLER DELAYS
}
```

In other words when `i=0`, `delayTime` will be 100ms, when `i=1`, `delayTime` is 200ms etc etc

Comment: Definitely going to try it. Thank a lot

Answer (score -1):

probably you want to sleep the thread for 500 milliseconds, then you can do this to slept your thread.

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(...)` is a hack in any code and almost always unnecessary. It's particularly bad in Android if used on the main (UI) thread as it can effectively hang the app and cause the system to generate an ANR (Application Not Responding) error.